# Replace missing dataframe with values from a reference dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is regarding a project using pandas in Python 3.7

I have a reference Dataframe df1

```
 code   name
0   1   A
2   2   B
3   3   C
4   4   D
```

And I have another bigger data frame df2 with missing values

```
 code   name
0   3   C
1   2   
2   1   A
3   4   
4   3   
5   1   B
6   4   
7   2   
8   3   C
9   2
```

As you see here df2 has missing values. 
How can I fill these values from the reference dataframe df1 using

Comment: `merge` then on `code` , of use `df2['name'].fillna(df2.set_index('code')['name'])` ?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following:

'''
df2 = df2.merge(df1,on='code',how='left')

'''